# Change pic.twitter.com....address links into thumbnails within tweet on website widget

Tags: twitter, thumbnails, default

Change pic.twitter.com address links into thumbnails within tweet in the iframe widget, i.e.,

Namely, tweets posted with images (in my website twitter widget) read as a text address. Thus, unknowing viewers skip over imagery in the tweets posted. (If they do happen to click the twitter address code, it redirects to a new tab/full page. Thus, the redirect will also make more sense with the thumbnail attribute).
So, to better inform the viewer, and give better tweet reception, my request is to turn the pic.twitter.com address links into thumbnails (of the target images) within tweets on my website widget.
What html and java script will force thumbnails into the default position instead of a mere code address???
 thanks, Francis

The full twitter widget code is as follows:
    
    
    
    new TWTR.Widget({
      version: 2,
      type: 'faves',
      rpp: 100,
      interval: 30000,
      title: 'Francis Michael Palazzolo',
      subject: '@turnLEDintoLEAD',
      width: 280,
      height: 350,
      theme: {
        shell: {
          background: '#faf7fa',
          color: '#325f33'
        },
        tweets: {
          background: '#faf7fa',
          color: '#000000',
          links: '#325f33'
        }
      },
      features: {
        scrollbar: true,
        loop: false,
        live: true,
        behavior: 'all'
      }
    }).render().setUser('turnLEDintoLEAD').start();Tweet to @turnLEDintoLEAD
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");>